# Как лишить конкретного пользователя или группу пользователей права исполнять исполняемые файлы Windows?

Tags: windows, администрирование

В интернете пишут про AppLocker, но не понимаю как заставить его работать (пользователь, к которому применено правило, как бы вообще его не замечает).

Comment: Выяснил, что AppLocker не работает только в Enterprise-редакции, а в Pro можно только создавать правила, но работать они не будут.

Comment: тут есть совсем маленькая проблема... при логине пользователя в систему от его имени запускаются некоторые системные процессы, которые являются исполняемыми файлами. Запуск чего вы хотите запретить?

Comment: Задание по лабе: запретить запуск *.exe для конкретного пользователя. Что имеет ввиду препод, понять тяжело, по этому я решил воспринимать буквально.

Comment: Буквально это не возможно. Можно запретить запуск из конкретных папок, это в правах папки настраивается. Уточняйте у препода.